# How to deploy Django apps on cwp Cent Os 7 using gunicorn and nginx

Tags: django, nginx, centos7, cwp

I have tried many times this artical https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-centos-7 but I am not getting the result.

I using dedicated server with CentOs 7 and CWP but I am not able to connect my wsi.py file through nginx server

I am doing first time deployment on centos7 cwp,So feel free to suggest me as fresher.

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific: what is broken? whats is OK? Do you have error logs? errors messages ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you could not configure nginx to pass your app's traffic. You need to update your domain's vhost in /etc/nginx/conf.d/vhosts/ in cwp by adding this:

```
location /static/ {
root /home/domain_account/public_html/;
expires 1d;
}
```